# Почему observable не присваивается

Tags: angular

Прилетает значение с сервера, которое я хочу присвоить в тип данных, а потом вывести. Как я понял, то они просто не успевают выводится в шаблон HTML.

Сервис:

```
getUserInfo(): Observable<Users>
{
    return this.http.get<Users>(`${environment.apiUrl}/Users`;
}
```

Компонент:

```
user: Users = new Users();

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUserInfo().subscribe((data:Users) => this.user = data);
    console.log(this.user)
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="auth" class="buttons-container">

  <div class="balance" style="color:white;">
    <b>Баланс:{{user.Balance}}</b>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="profile" routerLink="profile">
    <a routerLink="profile"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если делать `this.userService.getUserInfo().subscribe((data:Users) => console.log(data));`, то данные есть, а если присвоить их к user, то undefined;

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вызов `subscribe` - это регистрация функции обратного aсинхронного вызова (у вас это стрелочная функция), которая начнет работу когда вы получите  данные get-запроса.

Если вы хотите вывести результат присвоения, то надо указать операторные скобки тела функции и перенести `console.log()` туда

```
this.userService.getUserInfo()
    .subscribe( (data: Users) => {
         this.user = {...data};
         console.log(this.user);
     });
```

Comment: Данные в console выводятся, но в html - нет.

Comment: @JessieRutherford this.user = {...data}